# Odoo Remove Sale Order Report's header and footer

Tags: odoo, qweb

I want to print a report similar to sale.order report (customized of course) but without printing the header and footer it must be blank.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Djamel-eddine Bouzegzeg

Yes, you can do it with a simple configuration.

Set `Layout` with `basic_layout` on `General Setting`-> `Document Layout`.

Comment: What I want to do duplicate an already customized sale report. how I can inherit this report whit basic layout ?

Comment: You don't need the header/footer in the odoo sale report right? if yes then just follow the configuration with set the 'basic layout' this template will work for you to make a report without header/footer. & yes if you have any other customization like o change the existing sale order report then you have to ask another question for this as for this questioning is not fit into it.